# How to install rgdal on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: r

I'm strugling to install `rgdal` library on Ubuntu 12.10.

Installation from within R results in error:

> Error: gdal-config not found The gdal-config script distributed with
>   GDAL could not be found. If you have not installed the GDAL libraries,
>   you can download the source from  http://www.gdal.org/ If you have
>   installed the GDAL libraries, then make sure that gdal-config is in
>   your path. Try typing gdal-config at a shell prompt and see if it
>   runs. If not, use: 
>   --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config' with appropriate values for your installation.
>
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
>   * removing ‘/home/rdk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rgdal’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rgdal’ had
>   non-zero exit status

[R-sig-Geo](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2010-June/008464.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found) SE questions and other websites pointed me to the requirements of `libgdal1-dev`.

But when I tried

> sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev

I end up with another error message

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgdal1-dev :
>   Depends: libgdal-dev but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to
>   correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Again - when I try to install `libgdal-dev` another dependencies error shows up

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgdal-dev :
>   Depends: libgeos-dev but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libspatialite-dev but it is not going to be installed

Again trying  `libgeos-dev` gives message:

```
Depends: libgeos-c1 (= 3.3.3-1.1) but 3.3.3-2~precise2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and `libspatialite-dev`:

```
Depends: libspatialite3 (= 3.1.0~rc2-1ubuntu1) but
3.1.0~rc2-2~precise1 is to be installed
```

Is there any way to tame those dependencies and have `rgdal` running in Ubuntu?

My `sessionInfo()`

> R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) 
>   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 installing libgdal-dev & libgdal1-dev worked fine - perhaps it is because Quantal (12.10) is quite new and the package maintainers haven't updated the right versions yet? (Actually, why is it saying it is going to install `3.3.3-2~precise2` when you are on quantal?)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Is correct.  I did this on QQbeta2 a few weeks ago, but I can't remember how.  Try setting the CRAN repository in /etc/apt/sources.list to `precise` rather than `quantal`.

Comment: Did you look whether you could get r-cran-rgdal via Michael's PPA?

Comment: mathematical.coffee: Might as well be tad too early then. Ari: I updated CRAN repo - thanks for the tip. Dirk: Pardon my ignorance - are we talking about https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/c2d4u

Comment: @radek given [Josh O'Brien's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/725675/16835) below for 14.04, it may be worth editing your question to make it more general for other Ubuntu releases. I think it'd be useful to have a canonical question for this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A more recent answer can be found here: http://robinlovelace.net/r/2013/11/26/installing-rgdal-on-ubuntu.html .

Essentially, the three following lines of code should sort it:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude # install aptitude as an alternative to apt-get
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev # install the package (you may have to respond to queries here)
sudo aptitude install libproj-dev # install the proj.4 projection library
```

Spent ages on this problem, so hope this updated answer is useful to others. Let me know if so!

Comment: Had a problem with `rgdal` one more time... and stumble upon my own question here. This time your solution solved the issue.

Comment: It **is** useful. Thank you so much for taking the time to record these steps.

Comment: sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgdal # this command also does it and installs the dependencies automatically

Answer (score 13):

Try running them all together and specifying the versions, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-c1=3.3.3-1.1 libspatialite3=3.1.0~rc2-1ubuntu1
```

apt-get does not like to downgrade packages, but it will if you specify it.

Comment: Thanks - that seemed to do the trick. Will future updates cause some conflict with such solution?

Comment: They may likely cause upgrade problems, yes. To prevent a package from being upgraded, run this for every package: `echo packagename hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

Answer (score 4):

Here in January 2016, on Ubuntu 14.04.2 (and with R 3.2.2), I needed the following to get both [**rgdal**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) and the complementary (and frequently very useful) [**gdalUtils**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/index.html) package installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libgdal1h
sudo apt-get -y install libgdal1-dev
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
Rscript 'install.packages(c("rgdal", "gdalUtils"))'
```

Update: As on January 2017, the version of libgdal is 1i, so the second line of code should read:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libgdal1i
```

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal by pressing (Ctrl+alt+T) and type following command.

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -f

(It will fix dependencies.)

> sudo apt-get autoremove

(removing Unnecessary  packages)

> sudo apt-get clean

(Clear cache)

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution (autoremove did not kick out anything) - unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: It removes if any unnecessary package, sometimes It becomes important to remove it when your system has it.

Answer (score 3):

To get rgdal to install on Ubuntu 12.04, I had to install (and hold) many version specific packages. Basically I tried each package and installed the required versions of the dependencies until I could work back up to the original goal, to install libgdal1-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libspatialite3=3.0.0~beta20110817-3
echo libspatialite3 hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-get install libspatialite-dev
sudo apt-get install libgeos-c1=3.3.3-1.1~pgdg12.4+1
echo libgeos-c1 hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-get install libgdal1=1.9.0-3.1~pgdg12.4+1
echo libgdal1 hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections

sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev
gdal-config # now works, and can now install rgdal
```